# How do I append Mongo DB aggregation results to an existing collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform several insertions on an existent Mongo DB collection using the following code

```
db.dados_meteo.aggregate( [
                  { $match : { "POM" : "AguiardaBeira" } },
                  { $project : {
                     _id : { $concat: [
                        "0001:",
                      { $substr: [ "$DTM", 0, 4 ] },
                      { $substr: [ "$DTM", 5, 2 ] },
                      { $substr: [ "$DTM", 8, 2 ] },
                      { $substr: [ "$DTM", 11, 2 ] },
                      { $substr: [ "$DTM", 14, 2 ] },
                      { $substr: [ "$DTM", 17, 2 ] }
                       ] },
                    "RNF" : 1, "WET":1,"HMD":1,"TMP":1 } },
                  { $out : "dados_meteo_reloaded" }
              ] )
```

But each time I change the $match parameters and make a new aggregation, Mongo DB deletes the previous documents and inserts the new result.

Could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to aggregate and merge the result into a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976569/how-to-aggregate-and-merge-the-result-into-a-collection)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't":

> > If the collection specified by the $out operation already exists, then upon completion of the aggregation, the $out stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection. The $out operation does not change any indexes that existed on the previous collection. If the aggregation fails, the $out operation makes no changes to the pre-existing collection.

As a workaround, you can copy the collection document specified by `$out` to a "permanent" collection just after aggregation, in one of a several ways (non of which is ideal though):

- [copyTo()](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) is the easiest, mind the Warning. Don't use other for small results.
- Use JS: `db.out.find().forEach(function(doc) {db.target.insert(doc)})`
- Use mongoexport / mongoimport

Comment: can't believe they didn't have a way to append. and this is a db that has millions in funding? pathetic.

Comment: Ori, your answer looks good. may be you want to edit it and add this option http://stackoverflow.com/a/37433640/2834978. db.col1.insert(db.col2.aggregate(...).toArray())

Answer (score 20):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the new [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) aggregation operator (similar to `$out`) allows ***merging*** the result of an aggregation pipeline into the specified collection:

Given this input:

```
db.source.insert([
  { "_id": "id_1", "a": 34 },
  { "_id": "id_3", "a": 38 },
  { "_id": "id_4", "a": 54 }
])
db.target.insert([
  { "_id": "id_1", "a": 12 },
  { "_id": "id_2", "a": 54 }
])
```

the `$merge` aggregation stage can be used as such:

```
db.source.aggregate([
  // { $whatever aggregation stage, for this example, we just keep records as is }
  { $merge: { into: "target" } }
])
```

to produce:

```
// > db.target.find()
{ "_id" : "id_1", "a" : 34 }
{ "_id" : "id_2", "a" : 54 }
{ "_id" : "id_3", "a" : 38 }
{ "_id" : "id_4", "a" : 54 }
```

Note that the `$merge` operator comes with [many options](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#syntax) to specify how to merge inserted records conflicting with existing records.

In this case (with the default options), this:

- keeps the target collection's existing documents (this is the case of `{ "_id": "id_2", "a": 54 }`)
- inserts documents from the output of the aggregation pipeline into the target collection when they are not already present (based on the `_id` - this is the case of `{ "_id" : "id_3", "a" : 38 }`)
- replaces the target collection's records when the aggregation pipeline produces documents existing in the target collection (based on the `_id` - this is the case of `{ "_id": "id_1", "a": 12 }` replaced by `{ "_id" : "id_1", "a" : 34 }`)

Comment: $merge has a limitation too, it will not allow merging into the same collection in which we are performing the aggregation

Comment: Starting `Mongo 4.4`, `$merge` can output to the same collection that is being aggregated: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#merge

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest thing ever, but as another alternative syntax (from a post-processing archive/append operation)...

```js
db.targetCollection.insertMany(db.runCommand(
{
    aggregate: "sourceCollection",
    pipeline: 
    [
        { $skip: 0 },
        { $limit: 5 },
        { 
            $project:
            {
                myObject: "$$ROOT",
                processedDate: { $add: [new ISODate(), 0] }
            }
        }
    ]
}).result)
```

I'm not sure how this stacks up against the forEach variant, but i find it more intuitive to read.