# How do I save the array I get by using $lookup on one collection in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, merge, lookup

I would like to know how to save a part of the document, the $lookup method return for me. Here is an example:

**How do I save only the abbreviation array into `eOTD_term` collection?**

I have two collections:

ex. doc from `eOTD_abbreviation`

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59bc32fd7d7934a6a7a47d08"),
        "abbreviationID" : "0161-1#AB-000282#1",
        "termID" : "0161-1#TM-623205#1",
        "abbreviation" : "CONSTR,LGHT"
    }
```

ex. doc from `eOTD_term`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59bc2d7e7d7934a6a7777540"),
    "termID" : "0161-1#TM-623205#1",
    "conceptID" : "0161-1#01-082401#1",
    "term" : "CONSTRUCT,LIGHT",
}
```

`termID` is my unique key that exist in both collections.

I have tried the following:

```
db.eOTD_term.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "eOTD_abbreviation",
      localField: "termID",
      foreignField: "termID",
      as: "abbreviation"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { abbreviation: { $ne: [] } }
  }
]);
```

And I get back (one of the docs the aggregation returns):

```
{emphasized text
    "_id" : ObjectId("59bc2d7e7d7934a6a7777540"),
    "termID" : "0161-1#TM-623205#1",
    "conceptID" : "0161-1#01-082401#1",
    "term" : "CONSTRUCT,LIGHT",
    "abbreviation" : [  <----------- THIS ARRAY 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59bc32fd7d7934a6a7a47d08"),
            "abbreviationID" : "0161-1#AB-000282#1",
            "termID" : "0161-1#TM-623205#1",
            "abbreviation" : "CONSTR,LGHT"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will save the content of abbreviation array back to eOTD_term:

```
db.eOTD_term.insertMany(
    db.eOTD_term.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "eOTD_abbreviation",
          localField: "termID",
          foreignField: "termID",
          as: "abbreviation"
        }
      },
      {
        $match: { abbreviation: { $ne: [] } }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$abbreviation"
      },
      {
       $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$abbreviation" }
      },
    ]).result,
    {
    ordered: false <-- prevents from failing on unique constraints
    }
)
```

However if the result of aggregation is big you may run out of memory.

You can also try using "$out" stage instead of insertMany: [How do I append Mongo DB aggregation results to an existing collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741457/how-do-i-append-mongo-db-aggregation-results-to-an-existing-collection)

Comment: It should be noted that simply placing `$unwind` directly following the `$lookup` makes the `$match` redundant and a lot more efficient due to [how MongoDB actually hanldes that combination internally](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#lookup-unwind-coalescence). Note also that `$out` would fail if the new "root" `_id` values are not unique, but would be generally preferable to feeding "all" results into `.insertMany()` without "batching" requests.